# Get collection have array element exists another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections

```
contracts

{
...
 "missDoctypes": ["NB01", "NB02", "NB05"]
...
} 

doctypes
{
...
"code": "NB01",
"activate": true
...
}
```

I need get all contracts which exists element of missDoctypes in doctypes have activate is true

PL/SQL same :

```
select * from contracts tb1 where exists(select * from doctypes tb2 where tb2.activate = true and tb2.code in tb1.missDoctypes)
```

Please help me,
Thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) to lookup doctypes that matches your criteria. Then based on the lookup result you can perform filtering.

```js
db.contracts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "doctypes",
      "let": {
        "missDoctypes": "$missDoctypes"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    true,
                    "$activate"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$code",
                    "$$missDoctypes"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "doctypesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "hasDoc": {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$doctypesLookup"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      hasDoc: true
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cYkeSbz2ArV) for your reference.